# Webpage jsp:includes header but doesn't use linked stylesheet

Tags: html, css, jsp, web-applications, jspinclude

I've got some problems with finding the right way to ask this question. But I hope you understand the problem and are able to help.

I've set up a really basic Maven Web-App, using jsp's.

At the moment I have 2 pages.

1. Index.jsp (Starting page with loginbutton)
2. Home.jsp (Home page after login)

I also have an `header.jsp` and a `footer.jsp`.
Both the index.jsp and the home.jsp use the header and footer.

In the header is a link to a `stylesheet`.
When I run the project.
Both `index.jsp` and `home.jsp` use the header (they've got the right  tag)
But only `index.jsp` uses the `stylesheet`.

Why doesn't `home.jsp` use the `stylesheet`, even when the header is included correctly.

Here are some images of the code to help you understand the situation.

The Project Structure

[image: The Project Structure]

Index.jsp with the include of header/footer.jsp

[image: Index.jsp with the include of header/footer.jsp]

Home.jsp with the same include of header/footer.jsp, only the path is different.
But they load correctly, except for the css.

[image: Home.jsp with the same include of header/footer.jsp]

And here is the Header.jsp, with the link to the stylesheet

[image: the Header.jsp, with the link to the stylesheet]

If you need more info, I'll be happy to give it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the Answer of @Rohit Gaikwad I was able to figure it out myself.

Turns out that you need to locate the css from the used page (so not only from `header.jsp` but also from `index/home.jsp`

So I changed the link to the stylesheet to the following:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default-header.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/default-header.css"/>
```

This way i can be used from the index.jsp and the home.jsp
*(still not sure why index.jsp can load the css from the `css/default-header.css` link, without browsing the folders using "../")*

Answer (score 1):

use the below code to link the css in header.jsp:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../css/default-header.css"/>
```

**Note:** you need to locate the resource properly, the "../" will search for resource in one step back folder.
 Currently your`header.jsp` will search the resource in `default` folder which is located at `webapp\pages\layouts\default` but your css is in `webapp\css` folder. Hence, you need to traverse back to locate that resource.

**Trick:** press `ctrl key` and click on the hyper-reference link, the resource should be opened directly if the link is correct. Else the resource cannot be located if incorrect path is provided.
Hope you are using an IDE.

For your query in comment,

1. your `index.jsp` file is in `layouts` folder so you have to include your header.jsp as `default/header.jsp`. right now, your code will search header.jsp in `layouts/layouts/default/header.jsp`
2. For `home.jsp` if you are able to access `footer.jsp` then `header.jsp` should be accessible in `header.jsp`. The code `../layouts/default/header.jsp` is correct in `home.jsp`.

Comment: I just tried it, sounds logical. When I use your code to link the css I can indeed ctrl-click it in my IDE, couldn't do that with the old link.

But, now the css won't load/be used on home AND index.jsp